# java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: session

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-search

I am working on a SpringMVC+CRUD+Hibernate Search example :

When I search for a particular text, it gives me this error :

```
**Error** : HTTP Status 500 - Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: session
I tried all the examples given here :

http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.hibernate.search.jpa.FullTextEntityManager, but nothing works :
```

My Code:

////////////////////////////search.jsp////////////////////////////

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"
    prefix="springForm"%>
     <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Search Page</title>
</head>
<body>

<%--   <ol>
    <li th:each="person : ${searchResults}">
      <b><span th:text="${person.name}"></span></b> - 
      <span th:text="${person.address}"></span> -
      <span th:text="${person.salary}"></span>
      <span th:text="${person.gender}"></span>
    </li>
  </ol> --%>
  <springForm:form action="/MainAssignment3/search" method="GET"
        commandName="person">
    <tr>
                <td>Enter Search Text:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="text">
                <input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="/MainAssignment3/search"></input>              </td>



            </tr>
        </springForm:form>
  <table border="1">
<tr>
    <th>id</th>
    <td>name<springForm:errors path='${person.name}' /></td>    
        <td>address<springForm:errors path='${person.address}' /></td>
    <td>gender<springForm:errors path='${person.gender}' /></td>        

    <td>salary<springForm:errors path='${person.salary}' /></td></tr>   
 <c:forEach var="p" items='${searchResults}' varStatus="status">
    <tr>

        <td>${p.id}</td>
        <td>${p.name}</td>
        <td>${p.address}</td>
        <td>${p.gender}</td>
        <td>${p.salary}</td>

    </tr>

</c:forEach> 


</table>

 <%--  <p th:if="${searchResults.isEmpty()}">
    <strong>Hint</strong>: the query "<a href='/search?query=any'>any</a>" 
    should return some results.
  </p> --%>

</body>
</html>
```

/////////////////////////////Implementation of the search method//////////

```
    package com.dao;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.persistence.Cache;
import javax.persistence.EntityGraph;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceUnitUtil;
import javax.persistence.SynchronizationType;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder;
import javax.persistence.metamodel.Metamodel;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.query.Query;
import org.hibernate.search.jpa.FullTextEntityManager;
import org.hibernate.search.jpa.FullTextQuery;
import org.hibernate.search.jpa.Search;
import org.hibernate.search.query.dsl.EntityContext;
import org.hibernate.search.query.dsl.QueryBuilder;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerHolder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.model.Person;

@Transactional
@Repository
public class PersonDAOImpl implements PersonDAO, java.io.Serializable {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    //private EntityManager em;
    //private FullTextEntityManager ftem;
    private EntityManagerFactory efact;






    private static final Logger logger = (Logger) LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(PersonDAOImpl.class);

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sf) {
        this.sessionFactory = sf;
    }

    public void save(Person p) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Session s = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = s.beginTransaction();
        s.saveOrUpdate(p);
        tx.commit();
        s.close();

        System.out.println("Record successfully inserted");

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public List<Person> list() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<Person> personsList = session.createQuery("from Person").list();
        for (Person p : personsList) {
            logger.info("Person List::" + p);
        }
        return personsList;

    }

    public void updatePerson(Integer id) {
        Session session = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory()
                .openSession();
        Person p = new Person();
        Person person = session.get(Person.class, p.getId());


        session.createQuery("from Person");
        person.setName(p.getName()); // modify the loaded object somehow
        session.update(person);
        //t.commit();
        session.close();

    }

    public Person getPersonById(int id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Person p = (Person) session.load(Person.class, new Integer(id));
        logger.info("Person loaded successfully, Person details=" + p);
        return p;
    }

    public void removePerson(Integer id) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

//      Transaction t = session.beginTransaction();
        Person p = (Person) session.load(Person.class, new Integer(id));
        session.delete(p);
//      t.commit();
        logger.info("Person deleted successfully, person details=");

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Person> search(String text) {
        /*// TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //  FullTextEntityManager ftEntityManager = EntityManagerHolder.getFullTextEntityManager(); 
        //FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager = (FullTextEntityManager) ((EntityContext) entityManager).get();
        FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager = org.hibernate.search.jpa.Search.getFullTextEntityManager(em);
        //FullTextSession fullTextEntityManager =Search.getFullTextSession(sessionFactory.getCurrentSession());
        QueryBuilder queryBuilder = fullTextEntityManager.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Person.class).get();
    org.apache.lucene.search.Query query = queryBuilder.keyword().onFields("name", "address", "salary","gender").matching(text).createQuery();
        //org.hibernate.search.jpa.FullTextQuery jpaQuery = fullTextEntityManager.createFullTextQuery(query, Person.class);
        FullTextQuery jpaQuery= fullTextEntityManager.createFullTextQuery(query, Person.class);
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<Person> results = jpaQuery.getResultList();
        em.refresh(Person.class);
        return results;*/
/*        // Create a Query Builder
        QueryBuilder qb = getFullTextEntityManager().getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Person.class).get();

        // Create a Lucene Full Text Query
        org.apache.lucene.search.Query luceneQuery = (org.apache.lucene.search.Query) qb.bool()
                .must(qb.keyword().onFields("name", "address", "salary","gender").matching(text).createQuery());


        Query fullTextQuery = (Query) getFullTextEntityManager().createFullTextQuery(luceneQuery, Person.class);

        // Run Query and print out results to console
        List<Person> result = (List<Person>) fullTextQuery.getResultList();

        return result;
}


 protected FullTextEntityManager getFullTextEntityManager() {
        if (ftem == null) {
            ftem = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(em);
        }
        return ftem;
    }

    *//**
     * Get the JPA Entity Manager (required for the DBUnit Tests).
     * @return Entity manager
     *//*
    protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return em;
    }

    *//**
     * Sets the JPA Entity Manager (required to assist with mocking in Unit Test)
     * @param em EntityManager
     *//*
    protected void setEntityManager(EntityManager em) {
        this.em = em;
    }

*/          EntityManager em = efact.createEntityManager();
        FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager =
            org.hibernate.search.jpa.Search.getFullTextEntityManager(em);
        em.getTransaction().begin();

        QueryBuilder qb = fullTextEntityManager.getSearchFactory()
            .buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Person.class).get();
        org.apache.lucene.search.Query luceneQuery = qb
          .keyword()
          .onFields("name", "address", "salary","gender")
          .matching(text)
          .createQuery();

        // wrap Lucene query in a javax.persistence.Query
        javax.persistence.Query jpaQuery =
            fullTextEntityManager.createFullTextQuery(luceneQuery, Person.class);

        // execute search
        List result = jpaQuery.getResultList();

        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.flush();
        em.close();

        return result;
} }
```

////////////////////////////Controller/////////////////////////////

```
@Controller
public class MainController {

    @Autowired
    private PersonService ps;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public ModelAndView listPersons(ModelAndView model) throws IOException {
        List<Person> listper = ps.list();
        model.addObject("personsList", listper);
        model.setViewName("index");
        return model;

    }

    @RequestMapping("/search")
    public ModelAndView search(String query, Model model,HttpServletRequest req)
    {
        String name = req.getParameter("name");
        String address = req.getParameter("address");
        String salary = req.getParameter("salary");
        String gender = req.getParameter("gender");
        model.addAttribute("name", name);
        model.addAttribute("address", address);
        model.addAttribute("salary", salary);
        model.addAttribute("gender", gender);
        List<Person> searchResults = null;
    searchResults = ps.search(query);
       //NullPointerException in the above line
        model.addAttribute("searchResults", searchResults);
        return new ModelAndView("search");
    }
```

/////////////////////////////////ServiceImplementation////////////////////

```
public List<Person> search(String text) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return pdao.search(text);
}
```

/////////////////////////**stacktrace**//////////////////////

```
  org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'springConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'ps': Error creating bean with name 'PersonService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'pdao': Error creating bean with name 'personDAOImpl' defined in file [C:\spring-tool 3.6. (64 bit)\sts-bundle\pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.0.2.SR2\base-instance\wtpwebapps\MainAssignment3\WEB-INF\classes\com\dao\PersonDAOImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManager] found for dependency [javax.persistence.EntityManager]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManager] found for dependency [javax.persistence.EntityManager]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'personDAOImpl' defined in file [C:\spring-tool 3.6. (64 bit)\sts-bundle\pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.0.2.SR2\base-instance\wtpwebapps\MainAssignment3\WEB-INF\classes\com\dao\PersonDAOImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManager] found for dependency [javax.persistence.EntityManager]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManager] found for dependency [javax.persistence.EntityManager]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'PersonService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'pdao': Error creating bean with name 'personDAOImpl' defined in file [C:\spring-tool 3.6. (64 bit)\sts-bundle\pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.0.2.SR2\base-instance\wtpwebapps\MainAssignment3\WEB-INF\classes\com\dao\PersonDAOImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManager] found for dependency [javax.persistence.EntityManager]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManager] found for dependency [javax.persistence.EntityManager]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'personDAOImpl' defined in file [C:\spring-tool 3.6. (64 bit)\sts-bundle\pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.0.2.SR2\base-instance\wtpwebapps\MainAssignment3\WEB-INF\classes\com\dao\PersonDAOImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManager] found for dependency [javax.persistence.EntityManager]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManager] found for dependency [javax.persistence.EntityManager]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency.
```

//////////////////////////////////////pom.xml/////////////////

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.springframework.samples.service.service</groupId>
    <artifactId>MainAssignment3</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>

        <!-- Generic properties -->
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

        <!-- Web -->
        <jsp.version>2.2</jsp.version>
        <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
        <servlet.version>2.5</servlet.version>


        <!-- Spring -->
        <spring-framework.version>4.3.2.RELEASE</spring-framework.version>

        <!-- Hibernate / JPA -->
        <hibernate.version>5.2.1.Final</hibernate.version>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <logback.version>1.0.13</logback.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.5</slf4j.version>

    </properties>

    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>


    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>

        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-search-engine</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.4.Final</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-search-orm</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.4.Final</version>
</dependency>


        <!-- Spring MVC -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency> <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId> 
            <version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version> </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency> <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId> <artifactId>jta</artifactId> 
            <version>1.1</version> </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
</dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Other Web dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>${jstl.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${servlet.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jsp.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring and Transactions -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging with SLF4J & LogBack -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Test Artifacts -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
</dependency>

        <dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
</dependency>


    </dependencies>
</project>
```

I tried **two approaches : Hibernate Session and JPA**

**Approach 1 : JPA**

DAO Implementation :

```
 @PersistenceUnit
        private EntityManagerFactory emf;
        private EntityManager em;
        private FullTextEntityManager ftem;

        public void createFullTextEntityManager() {
            em = emf.createEntityManager();
            ftem = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(em);
        }

@Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Person> search(String text) throws InterruptedException {
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(em);

            em.getTransaction().begin();

            fullTextEntityManager.createIndexer().startAndWait();
            QueryBuilder qb = fullTextEntityManager.getSearchFactory()
                    .buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Person.class).get();
                org.apache.lucene.search.Query luceneQuery = qb
                  .keyword()
                  .onFields("name", "address", "salary","gender")
                  .matching(text)
                  .createQuery();

                // wrap Lucene query in a javax.persistence.Query
                javax.persistence.Query jpaQuery =
                    fullTextEntityManager.createFullTextQuery(luceneQuery, Person.class);

                // execute search
                List result = jpaQuery.getResultList();

                em.getTransaction().commit();
                em.close();
                return result;




}}
```

**Approach 2 : Hibernate Session**

DAOImpl :

```
@Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    private Session session=null;

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sf) {
        this.sessionFactory = sf;
    }


    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked", "deprecation" })
    public List<Person> search(String text) throws InterruptedException{

        FullTextSession fullTextSession = Search.getFullTextSession(session);
        try {
            Transaction tx = fullTextSession.beginTransaction();
            org.hibernate.search.query.dsl.QueryBuilder qb = fullTextSession.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Person.class ).get();
            org.apache.lucene.search.Query query = qb.keyword().onFields("name", "address", "salary","gender").matching(text).createQuery();
            org.hibernate.Query hibQuery = fullTextSession.createFullTextQuery(query, Person.class);
             List result = hibQuery.list();
             Iterator<Person> it = result.iterator();
             while (it.hasNext()) {
                   Person p = (Person) it.next();
                   System.out.println(p);
                  }
                  tx.commit();

        }
        finally{
            session.close();
        }


    return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: The CRUD operations are working fine - I am getting this error when I test the search operation by entering a search text

Comment: Does anybody know how to resolve this?

Comment: Update : I recently tried changing the search logic as given here https://dzone.com/articles/jpa-searching-using-lucene. Didn't work.

Comment: I have updated my question with another code which I tried for the search functionality. Now, I get the NullPointerException

Comment: You said that the CRUD operations are working fine but in the same time, you said that entityManager is null. Could you explain more about the situion? For example, in which line did you get the `NullPointerException`? You can do it by adding a comment after the NullPointException line.

Comment: I am getting the NullPointerException on the line searchResults = ps.search(query); in the controller. I also get that exception in my serviceimplementation –

Comment: Which line is `com.dao.PersonDAOImpl.search(PersonDAOImpl.java:174)`? Maybe the `EntityManagerFactory efact` is null, so it cannot create an entity manager.

Comment: No it is not null. I have just declared it as private : private EntityManagerFactory efact;  . Wait. I will update my question with my entire Implementation of DAO

Comment: I have updated my question with my new stacktrace

Comment: I debugged it. The error is on the line   QueryBuilder qb = fullTextEntityManager.getSearchFactory()

Comment: How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

The version of hibernate-core is set to *5.2.1.Final*, while hibernate-entitymanager is set at *5.1.0.Final*: these are not compatible, the versions have to be the same in the case of hibernate-entitymanager and hibernate-core.

Hibernate Search uses its own versioning, and the version you have picked *5.5.4.Final* is compatible with Hibernate ORM *5.1.0.Final* but NOT with *5.2.1.Final*.

So, I would suggest:

- hibernate-core 5.1.1.Final
- hibernate-entitymanager 5.1.1.Final
- hibernate-search-orm 5.5.4.Final

There's no need to depend on hibernate-search-engine as this is a dependency of hibernate-search-orm.

Comment: So these version updates have to be made in which one of the two approaches I used?? The 'Hibernate Session' approach or the JPA approach?

Comment: Both approaches should use these versions.

Comment: Should I also change the <hibernate.version>5.2.1.Final</hibernate.version> to 5.1.1?

Comment: Not Working. I get the exception : org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'springConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'ps':

Comment: I don't know Spring Boot, that's likely another problem. I am sure of the versions I have suggested you, trust me that's correct as I released these libraries myself ;)

Comment: So now what should I do?

Comment: Worked for me (Thanks to **System Requirements** section of HS doc [link](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#_system_requirements) ) ! 

But...Which further version of Hibernate Search will be compatible with Hibernate-core ?

Answer (score 0):

"efact" attribute is null ,you are not injecting "efact" via xml (because there is no setter or constructor in your code to do that) and also you are not using annotation.
Then  you have to add @Autowired on the "EntityManagerFactory efact" or use xml.

Comment: worked. But now, the error is org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: session

Comment: The exception is on the line   QueryBuilder qb = fullTextEntityManager.getSearchFactory()

Comment: I debugged it. The error is on the line QueryBuilder qb = fullTextEntityManager.getSearchFactory()

Comment: any suggestions??

Comment: Now, I get this : java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index;

Comment: I have tried both approaches : Hibernate Session and JPA. In Hibernate Session, I get the error 'Cannot Create FullTextEntityManager from a null EntityManager'

Comment: In JPA, I got the NoSuchFieldError Exception

Answer (score 0):

Try to change dependency of **hibernate-core** from  **5.2.1.Final** to **5.0.9.Final** in pom.xml file. You can read more about this in documentation of the hibernate-search http://hibernate.org/search/documentation/getting-started. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

hibernate-search-orm 5.5 does not support Hibernate-core:5.2.

try to update dependency **hibernate-search-orm**.

I am using 5.7.0.Beta2 and waiting for stables versions.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Hibernate Search with 2 approachs, using JPA or Hibernate session. There's nothing wrong to mix them, since Hibernate EntityManager is built on top of the core of Hibernate and Hibernate Annotations. However, I don't suggest you to do it, because it would complicate the situation and make learning Hibernate Search more difficult.

### JPA

```
@Transactional
@Repository
public class PersonDAOImpl implements PersonDAO, Serializable {

    @PersistenceUnit
    private EntityManagerFactory emf;
    private EntityManager em;
    private FullTextEntityManager ftem;

    public void createFullTextEntityManager() {
        em = emf.createEntityManager();
        ftem = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(em);
    }

    public List<Person> search(String keyword) {
        // TODO your logic here with full-text entity manager ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

### Hibernate Session

```
@Transactional
@Repository
public class PersonDAOImpl implements PersonDAO, Serializable {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    private Session session;
    private FullTextSession fts;

    public void createFullTextSession() {
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        fts = Search.getFullTextSession(session);
    }

    public List<Person> search(String keyword) {
        // TODO your logic here with full-text session ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

See the [Getting started with Hibernate Search](http://hibernate.org/search/documentation/getting-started/) to get a complet official tutorial.

Comment: If I use the first approach, what changes will be made to my pom.xml? I included hibernate-jpa-2.0-api adn removed spring-data-jpa dependency. It gave me an UnsatisfiedDependencyException

Comment: I have included the pom.xml for the 1st approach that you mentioned

Comment: I get the java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index;

Comment: @Nishil the method `javax.persistence.Table.indexes()` is introduced in  introduced in JPA 2.1. So you need to update `hibernate-jpa-2.0-api` to `hibernate-jpa-2.1-api`.

Comment: I have spring-data-jpa dependency. should I remove it?

Comment: so that I can use hibernate-jpa-2.1-api without any dependency conflict?

Comment: hibernate-jpa-2.1-api is not helping. Now , I am getting an Unsatisfied Dependency exception

Comment: I have updated my pom.xml. Now, I am getting another Unsatisfied Dependency exception. I have also updated my stacktrace

Comment: I didn't include the spring annotations, please check my updates. @Nishil

Comment: I have tried both approaches : Hibernate Session and JPA. In Hibernate Session, I get the error 'Cannot Create FullTextEntityManager from a null EntityManager'

Comment: In JPA, I got the NoSuchFieldError Exception

Comment: I have updated my question with the codes of both approaches

Comment: @Nishil, I'm sorry that I'm not able to help you further, because many questions are based on other problems, e.g. spring, Hiberante ORM. And I'm still a student... I suggest you to seperate this question into different smaller questions and post them on Stack Overflow, other people might be able to help you. And you need to make sure you understand what is session and JPA before going into Hibernate Search. Thing becomes complicated very fast.

Comment: Does anybody else have an idea about this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121904/discussion-between-nishil-and-mincong-huang).

Comment: There's nothing wrong in using Hibernate Search and mixing EntityManager and Session approach.

Comment: @Sanne, when you take a look on the [post's revisions](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39140082/revisions), you will understand that there're various surrounding problems. I still believe that by spliting them into 2 approachs can provide a better overview of different typical usages. However, I agree with you and therefore, I updated my answer.